# Folders from the sidebar are not showing

Tags: directory

How do i restore the folders that were showing on the sidebar and the general folder look. I only see the content not the folder!

Please Advise

Comment: Did you change the desktop theme? Some of the themes don't seem to pick up folder icons and just leave a space. Set desktop theme back to default and see if your folders reappear.

Comment: Yes I did. I changed it back and we're good! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pressing F9  enables and disables the sidebar view. =)

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Sidebar' there is an arrow to the right of 'Favorites' that when clicked will hide and show the folders. Took me a while to figure this out when it happened to me.

[Click on arrow to the right of 'Favorites in Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2BTm.png)

To change which folders are shown in the sidebar, you can go through Finder:Preferences:Sidebar